# Fullscreen TMUX sessions selection

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, tmux

I've found [TMUX](http://tmux.github.io/)'s `choose-tree` command to be quite useful when navigating between sessions, but I dislike it only displaying inside of the current pane. I'd prefer it to overtake my entire screen.

Inside my `tmux.conf` I'm attempting to write something to do just that, but haven't quite figured it out:

```
# ~/.tmux.conf
bind-key a resize-pane -Z \; choose-tree
```

My trigger command `Ctrl-a + a` will zoom the current tmux pane to be fullscreen and run choose-tree inside of it. Unfortunately this leaves the pane zoomed in.

Any ideas how I can unzoom the pane afterwards, or a different approach for fullscreen TMUX session selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clear from the documentation, but you can use the `-c` parameter to execute a command when you choose the window.
In this way you can toggle back the pane and then switch to the selected window:

```
# ~/.tmux.conf
bind-key a resize-pane -Z \; choose-tree -u -c "resize-pane -Z \; select-window -t '%%'"
```

tmux v2.6 include a new implementation of the `choose-tree` command that does not support anymore `-u` and `-c` commands.
The new syntax for this version to achieve the same is:

```
# ~/.tmux.conf
bind-key a resize-pane -Z \; choose-tree "resize-pane -Z \; select-window -t '%%'"
```

Comment: I like this idea, but it's not working for me, for some reason. Running tmux 2.6. As soon as I add any arguments to the `choose-tree` call the binding stops working entirely. Not sure why.

Comment: tmux rewrote the choose-tree implementation during the summer and the new implementation included in v2.6 does not support any more the `-c` parameter. At this moment I'm trying to understand if there's another way to pass a command to execute when an item has been choosen

Answer (score 4):

With Tmux v2.7 zooming the pane for session-selection gets fairly simple, just add the `-Z` [option](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#choose-tree)

`# ~/.tmux.conf
bind-key a choose-tree -Z`